# Yesod Redirect method GET PUT DELETE Which one?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have the following routes definition:

```
mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
/ ImagesR GET POST
/image/#ImageId ImageR DELETE
/static StaticR Static getStatic
/echo-body EchoBodyR PUT
|]
```

and in one of the handlers, there is `redirect ImagesR`. So which GET,POST or DELETE will be called after redirection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx), the redirect can be performed using either the same method, or simple GET.

And [redirect](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.6/yesod-core-1.4.32/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:redirect) documentation in Yesod says, that it always uses GET.